# Removing item from collection change its type - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`. This code retrieves users belonging to a company and return them to the client side.

The following query is used to get the user of the company

```
$users = User::where('company_id', '=', $idCompany)
            ->with([
                'roles' => function($q) {
                    $q->whereBetween('level', [50, 999]);
                }
            ])->get();
```

### Situation A

```
return $users;
```

`$users` is an array of objects `[{user1}, {user2}]`

### Situation B

```
 foreach($users as $key=> $user) {
   if(count($user->roles) == 0){$users->forget($key);}
 }
return $users;
```

I remove some item from the collection and the

`$users` is an object of objects `{{user1}, {user2}}`

Removing an item from the collection seems to change the type of the variable `$users`

1. How could I remove some item from the collection while maintaining
   the array of object?

### EDIT

Here is the correct query

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->whereBetween('level', [50, 999]);
        })
            ->with('roles')
            ->where('company_id', '=', $idCompany)
            ->get();

        return $users;
```

Comment: Why don't you just filter thru your collection, `return $users->filter(function($user) { return $user->roles->count(); });`. Also I think your first query is incorrect, you should be using `whereHas` in place of `with`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manipulating the collection, you need to add `->all()` to get the remaining collection;

```
return $users->all();
```

You could also do it this way

```
$filtered = $users->reject(function ($value, $key) {
    return count($user->roles) == 0;
});

return $filtered->all();
```

As proposed by Alex in the comments, you could use `whereHas()` instead of `with()` to get directly all the users having a role between 50 and 999

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('level', [50, 999]);
})
->where('company_id', '=', $idCompany)
->get();
```

Comment: But I would like to eager load the roles of the users. I would need a `whereHas`  along with a `with`

Comment: `  $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->whereBetween('level', [50, 999]);
        })
            ->with('roles')
            ->where('company_id', '=', $idCompany)
            ->get();
        
        return $users;`